# Setting foreground for whole Windows Phone's application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone

How to change foreground color for all controls in the application? I need to change color for: textboxes, textblocks, borders of buttons.

It will take too long to do it one by one (over 100 controls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what styles are for. You can add styles in your `app.xaml` file. Something like:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are programming for Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) or later, you can use a [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in your `App.xaml` file, add the following code inside your `Application.Resources` tag and customize as needed. The styles will be applied to all Pages in your application (you can still override individual properties directly in the corresponding element tags).

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank's! I didn't think that it will so easy! Works perfectly!